# different results running same app locally and remotely - windows app

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008

Something weird is happening with my application. When I am running it locally I am getting the results as they should be, normal decimal number. But when I am running the same application from server, the decimal number is divided by 100. 
I am using the same code, deploying the same app, and I am wondering why that is happening. 
Every advice is welcome. Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: Please give an example of the code which has problems.

Comment: Few ideas: compare culture, and check how you are deploying the code --- you could have conditional compilation/Debug settings on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously you server is running with a different locale.

Whenever you go from string to decimal, the locale (CultureInfo) matters.

For example, `ConvertToDecimal("1.00")` can give `1` or `100` depending on whether the `.` is set as the decimal separator or the thousands separator.

To prevent this, always use `ConvertToDecimal("1.00", someCulturInfo)`.

You can only rely on the default when the string is by definition in the users locale.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake thanks for useful information. Please keep us updated.